# defining custom color pallete in R

Tags: r

Hey I want to create my own custom palette of color in R using the brewer.pal() function. And then I want to view it using the image function.

```
 ny<-brewer.pal(7,"Blues")
 image(x=1:7,y=1,z=as.matrix(1:7),col=ny)
```

This code gives 7 shdes of blue, however i want to give my own choice of 7 different colors.

```
image(x=1:7,y=1,z=as.matrix(1:7),col=c("Reds","Blues"))
```

I thought of trying this function, but its obvious wrong. Can someone please help me. I specifically want to use the brewer.pal() and image() funcions

Comment: Is there an issue with using another set of colours from RColorBrewer? eg. Set1, Set2 or Set3? If you want to use specific colours from each of these sets, I usually extract the hexadecimal code (which will be within your ny object).

Comment: @SamPassmore yes, I tried with different colors. It still doesnt work. If you see the code i posted for just "blues", it works fine.

Comment: This works for me, and what I meant by Set1, Set2 & Set3. 
ny<-brewer.pal(7,"Set3")
image(x=1:7,y=1,z=as.matrix(1:7),col=ny)
The second codeblock you have doesnt refer to the brewer.pal function, so that is why that isn't working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you'd prefer a gradient between 2+ colors of your choosing, you could also use `colorRampPalette`

```
   pretty = colorRampPalette(c('#EF6780', '#80ef67', '#6780ef'))
   image(x=1:7,y=1,z=as.matrix(1:7),col=pretty(200))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can specify colors as hexadecimal colors in **R**. For example

```
image(x=1:7,y=1,z=as.matrix(1:7),col= "#CC6666")
```

References: 
http://www.color-hex.com/ 
http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Colors_(ggplot2)/